# How to await an Array of async Tasks without blowing the stack?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, continuations, continuation-passing

A large array of `Task`s blows the stack if you want to await them all, even if the array fold is stack-safe, because it yields a large deferred function call tree:

```js
const record = (type, o) =>
  (o[type.name || type] = type.name || type, o);

const thisify = f => f({});

const arrFold = f => init => xs => {
  let acc = init;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < xs.length; i++)
    acc = f(acc) (xs[i], i);

  return acc;
};

const Task = task => record(
  Task,
  thisify(o => {
    o.task = (res, rej) =>
      task(x => {
        o.task = k => k(x);
        return res(x);
      }, rej);
    
    return o;
  }));

const taskMap = f => tx =>
  Task((res, rej) =>
    tx.task(x => res(f(x)), rej));

const taskOf = x =>
  Task((res, rej) => res(x));

const taskAnd = tx => ty =>
  Task((res, rej) =>
    tx.task(x =>
      ty.task(y =>
        res([x, y]), rej), rej));

const taskAll =
  arrFold(tx => ty =>
    taskMap(([x, y]) =>
      xs => x => xs.concat([x]))
        (taskAnd(tx) (ty)))
          (taskOf([]));

const inc = x =>
  Task((res, rej) =>
    setTimeout(x => res(x + 1), 0, x));
    
const xs = Array(1e5).fill(inc(0));

const main = taskAll(xs);

main.task(console.log, console.error);
```

In order to solve this issue you usually break the function calls with a special data structure and a corresponding trampoline:

```
const Call = f => (...args) =>
  ({tag: "Call", f, args});

const deferredRec = step => {
  while (step && step.tag === "Call")
    step = step.f(...step.args);

  return step;
};
```

Now the decisive function in `taskAll` seems to be `taskMap`, where two operations wind up the stack:

```
const taskMap = f => tx =>
  Task((res, rej) =>
    tx.task(x => res(f(x)), rej));
//               ^^^^^^^^^
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

const taskMap = f => tx =>
  Task((res, rej) =>
    Call(f => tx.task(f)) (x => Call(res) (f(x)), rej));
```

While the adjustment prevents the stack overflow, it unfortunately stops the computation from running to completion, that is to say the final continuation `console.log` is never called but the computation stops after calling `inc` once (see line `A`):

```js
const deferredRec = step => {
  while (step && step.tag === "Call")
    step = step.f(...step.args);

  return step;
};

const Call = f => (...args) =>
  ({tag: "Call", f, args});

const record = (type, o) =>
  (o[type.name || type] = type.name || type, o);

const thisify = f => f({});

const arrFold = f => init => xs => {
  let acc = init;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < xs.length; i++)
    acc = f(acc) (xs[i], i);

  return acc;
};

const Task = task => record(
  Task,
  thisify(o => {
    o.task = (res, rej) =>
      task(x => {
        o.task = k => k(x);
        return res(x);
      }, rej);
    
    return o;
  }));

const taskMap = f => tx =>
  Task((res, rej) =>
    Call(f => tx.task(f)) (x => Call(res) (f(x)), rej));

const taskOf = x =>
  Task((res, rej) => res(x));

const taskAnd = tx => ty =>
  Task((res, rej) =>
    tx.task(x =>
      ty.task(y =>
        res([x, y]), rej), rej));

const taskAll =
  arrFold(tx => ty =>
    taskMap(([xs, x]) =>
      xs.concat([x]))
        (taskAnd(tx) (ty)))
          (taskOf([]));

const inc = x =>
  Task((res, rej) =>
    setTimeout(x => (console.log("inc"), res(x + 1)), 0, x)); // A
    
const xs = Array(3).fill(inc(0));

const main = taskAll(xs);

deferredRec(main.task(console.log, console.error));
```

How can this be done right? Is there a more general approach for all sorts of CPS code? Please note that I don't want to give up on lazyness.

Comment: _"...the computation stops after calling inc once (see line A):"_ - Because that's how [`Array.prototype.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) works. It assigns the value returned by `inc(0)` to all spots of the array. It doesn't call `inc(0)` once per index: `xs[0] === xs[1] === xs[2]`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. `inc` (line `A`) just needs to apply the trampoline:

```js
const deferredRec = step => {
  while (step && step.tag === "Call")
    step = step.f(...step.args);

  return step;
};

const Call = f => (...args) =>
  ({tag: "Call", f, args});

const record = (type, o) =>
  (o[type.name || type] = type.name || type, o);

const thisify = f => f({});

const arrFold = f => init => xs => {
  let acc = init;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < xs.length; i++)
    acc = f(acc) (xs[i], i);

  return acc;
};

const Task = task => record(
  Task,
  thisify(o => {
    o.task = (res, rej) =>
      task(x => {
        o.task = k => k(x);
        return res(x);
      }, rej);
    
    return o;
  }));

const taskMap = f => tx =>
  Task((res, rej) =>
    Call(f => tx.task(f)) (x => Call(res) (f(x)), rej));

const taskOf = x =>
  Task((res, rej) => res(x));

const taskAnd = tx => ty =>
  Task((res, rej) =>
    tx.task(x =>
      ty.task(y =>
        res([x, y]), rej), rej));

const taskAll =
  arrFold(tx => ty =>
    taskMap(([xs, x]) =>
      xs.concat([x]))
        (taskAnd(tx) (ty)))
          (taskOf([]));

const inc = x =>
  Task((res, rej) =>
    setTimeout(x => deferredRec(res(x + 1)), 0, x)); // A
    
const xs = Array(1e4).fill(inc(0));

const main = taskAll(xs);

deferredRec(main.task(console.log, console.error));
```